# Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to update a table through sequelize. but I am getting error-**Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'** . My code is

```
db.billingplan.findById(req.params.id).then(result=>{
            result.update({
                'poregisterReference': String(req.body.reference),
                'po_number' : req.body.po_number,
                'billing_milestone': String(req.body.billing_milestone),
                'billing_milestone_probable_date':checkDate(req.body.billing_milestone_probable_date),
                'milestone_blling_amount':req.body.milestone_billing_amount,
                'actual_billing_date': actual_billing_date,
                'bill_number':req.body.bill_number,
                'bill_amount':bill_amount,
                'tax_rate':tax_rate,
                'tds_rate':tds_rate,
                'recovery_date': recovery_date,
                'recovery_amount':recovery_amount ,
                'utr_number': String(req.body.utr_number),
                'bill_amount_with_tax': bill_amount_with_tax,
                'net_recoverable_after_tds': net_recoverable_after_tds ,
                'short_recovery': recovery_amount - net_recoverable_after_tds,
                'recovery_period': dayDiff(recovery_date, actual_billing_date )
            });
        });
```

I have used this way to update without using where clause but never had this problem, so I am guessing thats not the problem. Can someone tell me what it is that I am doing wrong here.
follwing is the stacktrace:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'
    at Query.formatError (D:\Users\Temp\Desktop\POregister\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:228:16)
    at Query.connection.query [as onResult] (D:\Users\Temp\Desktop\POregister\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:55:23)
    at Query.Command.execute (D:\Users\Temp\Desktop\POregister\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:30:12)
    at Connection.handlePacket (D:\Users\Temp\Desktop\POregister\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:515:28)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\Users\Temp\Desktop\POregister\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:94:16)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\Users\Temp\Desktop\POregister\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:77:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Temp\Desktop\POregister\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:102:29)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20)
```

Comment: This comment in its entirety is a guess: Sequelize is constructing SQL by concatenating strings, and when it came to one of the numbers it got back `NaN` as a numeric value and dutifully converted this to a string and concatenated it in, resulting in something like ` ... columnName = NaN ...`. When the database engine tried to execute this it saw a clause that is basically `... COLUMN = COLUMN ...`, but `NaN` does not exist as a column and thus the error.

Comment: But, the update statement executed by sequelize are always in quotes, so that can't happen, as far as i understand

Comment: Something is undefined in your req.body... following parameters could be one of them `poregisterReference`, `billing_milestone`,`utr_number`,`recovery_period`... console them

Comment: One of the numeric expressions in your statement results in a `NaN`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen That works.. Thanks. but the error output doesn't make sense :/

Comment: It made sense to me, though I also think this is a bug in Sequelize. It should definitely have a way to handle `NaN` and similar non-numeric values wrapped in a numeric type. If you dump the SQL used you'll see it for yourself, though I don't know node nor sequelize so I cannot tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is to check the values of what you set as FindOptions. I think one of them is `NaN`. I had the same error.

[image: As you can seed it offset is NaN]

**NOTE** i write my options in a variable and then print it.

```
let options = {
    where: {},
    limit: page?.limit ?? PHONE_LIMITATION,
    attributes: [
      Phone.col.id,
      Phone.col.phone,
      Phone.col.userId,
      Phone.col.createdAt,
      Phone.col.updatedAt,
    ],
    offset: page?.offset ?? 0,
};
console.log(options);
// other stuff
```

Comment: greatly helped to find the issue quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check how you defined associations of your tables ( hasOne(), belongsTo() etc). I defined unnecessary association somewhere in my code and had a similar problem. This introduces unwanted columns/attributes.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).